# Backend without traditional Authentication mechanism, use cryptography instead

Tags: authentication, cryptography

**Context**: I have a mobile app, and I don't have, and will not, implement a traditional authentication flow (email/pw, social login). Instead, I would like to leverage asymmetric key encryption.

**Requirements**: For the sake of simplicity, let's imagine a simple backend with one `User` model, which only has one field: `favorite_number`.

- a user can CRUD a `User` model on the backend.
- a user cannot CRUD another user's `User` model.

**Potential solution**:

- Alice generates a private/public key pair on her mobile device. She keeps the private key securely on-device.
- Alice makes a network request (let's say a RESTful POST request) to the backend, with the following payload:

```
{
  "public_key": {Alice's public key},
  "favorite_number": 42,
  "signature": sign_with_private_key(42)
}
```

where `sign_with_private_key(42)` is the signature of the message `42`, signed with Alice's private key.

- The backend receives the above payload, verifies that the signature matches the public key and the `favorite_number`, and saves the following information in its DB (assume SQL below):

```
| public_key | favorite_number | signature |
| ---------- | --------------- | --------- |
| 0x...      | 42              | 0x..      |
```

- Alice wants to read her favorite number:

  - Alice sends `GET /api/get_nonce?public_key={Alice's public key}` to the backend
  - The backend looks in the DB the row with Alice's public key, and returns its `signature` column ONLY
  - Alice decrypts the `signature` with her local private key, it returns `42`.
- Bob wants to read Alice's favorite number, he calls the same endpoint `GET /api/get_nonce?public_key={Alice's public key}`, get's Alice's favorite_number signature, but cannot decrypt it.
- Bob wants to modify Alice's favorite number, but cannot, because he can't compute the signature of the `favorite_number` message.

**Caveats** (which I can live with):

- If Alice loses her phone or uninstalls the app, all her account information on the backend will be lost.

**Additional assumptions**:

- The DB cannot be directly accessed by other party than the backend (and DB administrator) itself. (clarification request by @kelalaka). But that's independent of authentication.

**Question**: Is this authentication scheme viable? Do you see any big security loopholes?

Comment: Signatures can be verified, so with Alice public key, an attacker to the DB can deduce 42 is signed by Alice.

Comment: If Bob sends `GET /api/get_nonce?public_key={Alice's public key}`, it's assumed that Bob already knows Alice's public key. The backend will return Alice's signature, which Bob can verify it's indeed Alice's, but Bob cannot know it's 42.

Comment: I'm seeing the 42 clearly on the table.

Comment: Right, but what I thought is that 42 is stored in DB, but the backend only returns the `signature` column of that DB.

Comment: That is my point, attacker download or access the DB, or a semi-honest DB administrator can extract this information.

Comment: @kelalaka I see. The problem of securing the DB layer is also present in traditional login-based backend architectures, so I want to keep it out of scope of this question.

Comment: Make it clear in your question, then inform me so that I can delete my comments.

Comment: You are confusing and conflating private key and public key operations. Alice's public key is presumed to be *public*, hence known to bob, hence bob can recover 42 solely from the signature scheme (which must one of the "signature with message recovery " schemes, an unstated assumption in your question).

Comment: I feel you. I was thinking to use Alice's public key as an unique identifier, a priori unguessable by Bob. But if Bob does somehow get hold of Alice's public key, he'll only hold Alice's public key and her signature of the message 42, and I **don't** want Bob to recover 42 from those 2 inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels a bit over-complicated. If Alice has a keypair, then Alice can simply sign requests, and the signature *is* the authentication. There's no particular reason to sign individual pieces of data. Just sign the requests themselves. For example:

```
{
  "request": {"message_id":123,"public_key":"...","favorite_number":42},
  "signature": signature_of('{"message_id":123,"public_key":"...","favorite_number":42}')
}
```

It is critical that you sign everything that is part of the request.

Note that requests need to be single-use, otherwise this is not secure. By single-use, I mean that a timestamp should be in the request and the same request should not be useable more than once. You can also use a message counter (especially since you only have one device that can connect). So the server always rejects messages ids equal to or smaller than the last id sent for this user.

Your approach is vulnerable to reuse of the value upon another key. For example, I could reuse "42" and assign it to some other thing like "hated_number." Or I could replay this message and reset Alice's favorite number to 42 after she has changed it to something else. Signing the entire request is a much better approach and avoids a number of these problems (as long as a request can't be reused).

If Alice wishes to protect the data from the administrator, then she should encrypt the data with a symmetric key, but that's independent of authentication.

A simpler way to implement this, provided the transport is trusted, is to let Alice generate a random 256-bit identifier, and simply use that as the authentication. A 256-bit identifier will always be sufficiently sparse that it is unguessable (guessing the identifier is precisely the same as guessing an AES-256 key). With that, simply knowing the identifier is sufficient to authenticate a request. This only works if the transport is trusted, but that's the same as any static credential (username+password, token, etc). By a trusted transport, I mean HTTPS with pinned certs, for example, or any similarly encrypted and authenticated transport.

Comment: Thanks. Could you expand on what you mean by signing the whole request? What would the HTTP headers and body look like?

Comment: Updated with an example. That said, I'd lean heavily towards the 256-bit random identifier rather than signatures, and leave message integrity to the transport rather than putting it inside the message. Getting signatures exactly right can be quite tricky.

Comment: My preference for this would be to select two 256-bit values. Use the first as an identifier, and use the second to encrypt the data. That way only Alice can change the data (because only Alice and the server have access to the identifier), and only Alice can read the data (because only Alice has access to the key).

Comment: Thanks for the example, understood. I see your point with one 256-bit value. But I feel that using two 256-bit values (one as identifier, one as AES key) has no benefit over a public/private key pair, and imo seems even slightly more complicated.

Am i correct that in the two 256-bit scheme, you still need to send `{
  "request": {"message_id":123,"id":"...","favorite_number":42},
  "signature": signature_of('{"message_id":123,"id":"...","favorite_number":42}')
}`, where `signature_of` is the AES encrypted message with the user's 2nd 256-bit value? What's the benefit of using 2 then?

Comment: No, with a 256-bit identifier, you don't need a signature. Forging the message would require guessing the identifier (assuming the transport is trusted and the identifier is never used for anything but authentication).

Comment: The model I'm discussing would look like `{"id": "...", "favorite_number": encrypted(key, 42)}`. That's all; no signatures required because integrity and authentication are already handled. And by adding encryption, it's a simple secure store, where the db owner doesn't have access either.